# Accessing global variables fails

Tags: r, authentication, makefile, environment-variables, global

I was trying to implement simple **authentication** in R that would store *credentials* outside of the source code under revision control. I'm aware of the approach using `options()` and `getOption()`, but using it would force me to remove project-level `.Rprofile` from revision control. I prefer to use another approach, based on exporting credentials' environment variables via `.bashrc` of an R-associated Linux user (`ruser`) and then reading these credentials in project-specific `.Rprofile` into global variables like this:

```
CB_API_KEY <<- Sys.getenv("CB_API_KEY")
```

However, accessing such global variables in R modules fails with message "object 'CB_API_KEY' not found". I suspect that the reason is that I source `.Rprofile` via separate calling `R CMD BATCH` in `Makefile`. Executing R modules, where I attempt to access these global variables, is done again via `Makefile` by separate call to `Rscript`. Therefore, it appears to me that *global environment* of the **first R session** is lost, hence access failures. I would appreciate your comments and advice on this issue.

UPDATE: The following is the contents of project-specific `.Rprofile` as well as the project's top-level and sub-project-level `Makefile` files, correspondingly.

`.Rprofile`:

```
# Execute global R profile first...
source("~/.Rprofile")

# ...then local project R setup

# Retrieve SRDA (SourceForge) credentials
SRDA_USER <<- Sys.getenv("SRDA_USER")
SRDA_PASS <<- Sys.getenv("SRDA_PASS")

# Retrieve CrunchBase API key
CB_API_KEY <<- Sys.getenv("CB_API_KEY")

# Another approach is to use options() and getOption(),
# but it requires removing this file from source control
options(SRDA_USER = "XXX", SRDA_PASS = "YYY", CB_API_KEY = "ZZZ")
```

Top-level `Makefile`:

```
# Major variable definitions

PROJECT="diss-floss"
HOME_DIR="~/diss-floss"
REPORT={$(PROJECT)-slides}

COLLECTION_DIR=import
PREPARATION_DIR=prepare
ANALYSIS_DIR=analysis
RESULTS_DIR=results
PRESENTATION_DIR=present

RSCRIPT=Rscript


# Targets and rules

all: rprofile collection preparation analysis results presentation

rprofile:
        R CMD BATCH ./.Rprofile

collection:
        cd $(COLLECTION_DIR) && $(MAKE)

preparation: collection
        cd $(PREPARATION_DIR) && $(MAKE)

analysis: preparation
        cd $(ANALYSIS_DIR) && $(MAKE)

results: analysis
        cd $(RESULTS_DIR) && $(MAKE)

presentation: results
        cd $(PRESENTATION_DIR) && $(MAKE)


## Phony targets and rules (for commands that do not produce files)

#.html
.PHONY: demo clean

# run demo presentation slides
demo: presentation
        # knitr(Markdown) => HTML page
        # HTML5 presentation via RStudio/RPubs or Slidify
        # OR
        # Shiny app

# remove intermediate files
clean:
        rm -f tmp*.bz2 *.Rdata
```

Sub-project-level `Makefile`:

```
# Major variable definitions

RSCRIPT=Rscript
#RSCRIPT=R CMD BATCH
R_OPTS=--no-save --no-restore --verbose
#R_OUT=> outputFile.Rout 2>&1

# --no-save --no-restore --verbose myRfile.R > outputFile.Rout 2>&1


# Targets and rules

collection: importFLOSSmole \
            importSourceForge \
            importAngelList \
            importCrunchBase

importFLOSSmole: getFLOSSmoleDataXML.R
        $(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<

importSourceForge: getSourceForgeData.R
        $(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<

importAngelList: getAngelListData.R
        $(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<

importCrunchBase: getCrunchBaseDataAPI.R
        $(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<

.PHONY: clean

# remove intermediate files
clean:
        rm -f tmp*.bz2 *.Rdata .Rout
```

Directory structure is typical:

```
+ `ruser` home directory
|____+ project's home directory
     |____ `import` sub-directory
     |____ project's other sub-directories
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please can you show us the contents of `Makefile` and `.Rprofile`.  In particular, we need to see the call to `Rscript` to see what command arguments are being passed to it.

Comment: @RichieCotton: Thank you for your comment and answer! Per your request, I updated my question with asked details. Sorry about the delay - I was offline.

Comment: Having `source("~/.Rprofile")` inside `.Rprofile` is weird.  That kind of crazy recursion could be causing problems.

Comment: Try adding `message("Inside .Rprofile")` to your `.Rprofile` file to see if it getting called.

Comment: @RichieCotton: 1) To place that statement in `.Rprofile` is actually a recommendation I've read in an R book, published by a well-known publisher. According to the author, this advice stems from the fact(?) that R, if sourcing a project-level `.Rprofile` file, won't automatically source the main one. Hence, the advice and no risk(?) of cyclical dependency; 1') Actually, my main `.Rprofile` is currently empty, I just source it for potential future changes; 2) Added `message` call: as expected, I get the message. But the **most important & magic** thing is that I don't see error message anymore!

Comment: @RichieCotton: (cont'd) So, looks like everything works as planned, despite how strange it might be for you and me. However, I'm curious about the reason of the error message. I try to make sure that I restart R session after making changes in `.Rprofile` files. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems unlikely that adding a message suddenly made the rest of the `.Rprofile` be sourced correctly, but it's up to you how much you care about knowing why it works. Consider just accepting it as good fortune and moving on.

Comment: @RichieCotton: I agree with you: moving forward! Thanks much for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like I figured out how to solve this problem. I created another `.Rprofile` in the project's sub-directory (`import`), where processing requires authentication, and moved there code retrieving environment variables' values into R global variables. I tested it and haven't seen the previous error message (knocking on wood!). *Additional benefit* is that now the code is more separated into functional areas and, thus, is *cleaner*.

**Lesson learned** (and the reason of all this trouble):

**Any** R session sources `.Rprofile` file in **any** [current] directory where it runs (I wrongfully assumed that R session sources `.Rprofile` file only once, on the initial run, and subsequent R sessions cannot do that).

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood this correctly, you have a shell script named `Makefile` which calls R in batch mode (`R CMD BATCH`) to source your `.Rprofile` file, and then later runs another R session via `Rscript`, where it can't find the variable that you definine in your `.Rprofile` file.

You are correct in noticing that global variables aren't persisted between sessions.

However, unless you are calling `Rscript` with the `--no-init-file` or `--vanilla` arguments, the `.Rprofile` file should be sourced on startup.

Adding `messages` to your `.Rprofile` will let you know if and when it gets called.

Comment: Again, thank you for the answer! I updated my question per your request. However, as you see, I'm calling `Rscript` without `--no-init-file` and `--vanilla` arguments. So, the reason of the issue might be that it's an `.Rprofile` in a project's sub-directory. Another potential reason might be how I start R sessions via `Makefile` files. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Sorry, I guess, it was too early for me to celebrate... I just found the reason of disappearing of the error message: when reverting back from the `options` approach, I commented out setting options in `.Rprofile`, but accidentally forgot to revert to accessing ENV-based global variables. I'm not sure where these options are stored (my guess would be `.RData`), but they seemed to persist across R session restarts. So, you and me were correct that global variables cannot magically persist across sessions.