# Unexpected output of data frame contents

Tags: r, debugging, makefile, dataframe, rstudio

After recent small changes in R code, I wanted to print contents of a data frame, resulting from these two lines of code:

```
data <- data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(startupData))
startups <- rbind.fill(data)
```

Then, assured that the data frame contents matches the expected result, I commented out the printout lines of code, to test the code again, before committing to a repository. However, to my great surprise, running the code still was producing the debug output. I tried multiple approaches (studied and modified `.Rprofile` files, `Makefile` files, even disabled `.RData` file), but to no avail.

Then I decided to try sourcing the same module from within RStudio and, voila - no output. To me, it clearly means that the reason of the unexpected behavior is outside of the module's code. But where? As I said, I checked all those R infrastructure files and they seem to be normal. The only two suspicious items that I can think of are: 1) my project's `GNU make` infrastructure (described in detail here: [Accessing global variables fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985888/accessing-global-variables-fails)); 2) `Rscript` magic (I see some of the duplication in command-line options). Or, something else... But, whatever the reason is, the only reason it could happen, given normal sourcing in RStudio, is IMHO, via some cached instructions/objects retained in R execution environment across multiple sessions and magically being activated during `Makefile`-controlled runs.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue!

UPDATE: I thought it might be useful to see information on running the session:

```
ruser@hostname:~/diss-floss/import$ make -n importAngelList
Rscript --no-save --no-restore --verbose getAngelListData.R

ruser@hostname:~/diss-floss/import$ make importAngelList
running
  '/usr/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore --no-save --no-restore --file=getAngelListData.R'

Loading required package: RCurl
Loading required package: methods
Loading required package: bitops
Loading required package: jsonlite
Loading required package: plyr

Retrieving AngelList data...

<UNEXPECTED OUTPUT IS PRODUCED HERE>
```

Comment: It's nearly impossible to address this without seeing the contents of `startupData` and an explicit discussion of how the current output differs from your intended output.

Comment: @Thomas: I think you misunderstood the issue, which is simply that I continue to see output, printing of which is commented (disabled), in other words, output, which is not supposed to be produced. The fact that it is indeed disabled is that sourcing the module within RStudio produces no output, as expected. So, the contents of the output is irrelevant to the issue. Please re-read my question for clarity.